# Changing case of translated compound properties

Tags: java, localization, resourcebundle

If I have a java property file with a property like this:

```
{0} are green
```

where {0} can be filled in by Apples or Oranges, that works fine for English, but suppose I have a language where the word order would be like this instead:

```
Green are {0}
```

Now I would like to substitute the {0} with a lower case version instead, like apples or oranges.

The translator of the language should be able to select the upper or lower case version, but I  haven't been able to find a way to do this. Do anyone have a clue about how to accomplish this?

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible with the vanilla resource bundle support. You'd either have to provide both versions and access them as `{0}` and `{1}` (in case you only have one parameter) or do the replacement yourself and provide some custom markup for that case.

Comment: I quickly looked into it and from what it seems one may be able to extend Format to make a custom formatting: {0, text, lowercase} for example. (Where "text" is a custom FormatType and "lowercase" is a custom FormatStyle) Has anyone done something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way via Apache ExtendedMessageFormat that would let me do exactly what I want. I could write a text format with a lowercase argument, allowing something like {0, text, lowercase} or just {0, lowercase} see [ExtendedMessageFormat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article2_4.html).

Unfortunately I'm also using wicket and since I can't force wicket to use the Apache version I guess I'm at a dead end with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are implementing this, but maybe you can use [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) from `Apache Commons` and abstract the process of selecting  the corresponding `Apple/apple` version, just wrap the full sentence and transform.

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("i aM.fine", {'.'}) = "I am.Fine"
```

Comment: I want to avoid having to change the source and be able to change things in the property files only. Sometimes I may want an all caps word in a translation for example.